# PHP Codeigniter error failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, ubuntu, permissions

I have been working on a project that uses codeigninter. I worked on it in Windows 7 and it was fine but after I moved this project on Ubuntu to work on it there, It gives me this error in every page/controller/method that I try to access:

```
Warning: require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/TS_Project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/TS_Project/index.php on line 202

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/TS_Project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/TS_Project/index.php on line 202
```

The `CodeIgniter.php` file does exist, the path to it is correct and I am able to read and write in it ( I can open it in a text editor and modify it freely). I tried changing the file permission to it using the `chmod` command but nothing happens. Why is permission denied to the `CodeIgniter.php` file?

Comment: fixed it, had to use `chomd 775` on the `TS_Project` folder

Comment: You should [post your solution as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @GrigorutaCristian You definitely should post this comment as a self answer. It fixed my issue right away.

Answer (score 21):

You need to change the permission of your TS_Project folder to 755.

You can do that by:

`sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/TS_Project`

Comment: i have the same issu, i tried the above command, but it still returning the error: Message:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/portfolioApis/application/../uploads/newImage.JPG): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: How about you try giving 777 to your entire portfolioApis by `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/portfolioApis`